# conda environment has access to system modules, how to prevent?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I noticed that when I create a new enviornment with conda, I can import python modules in that environment that were NOT installed there.

Example with keras:
Although the module is NOT in that enviornment:

```
(py2) user@user-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ conda list keras
# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/py2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

I can still import it, apparently from the system (user) install, outside conda!

```
(py2) user@user-Precision-7920-Tower:~$ python
Python 2.7.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar  5 2020, 14:56:06) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> keras.__file__
'/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.pyc'
```

In fact, python inside conda has access to non-conda paths!

```
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> sys.stdout.write("\n".join(sys.path))

/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python27.zip
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages               <-- 
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages>>>
```

Conda is supposed to keep things isolated. How did this path endd up in here, and how to avoid this from happening?

UPDATE:

My user-level python is 2.7, and I noticed this behavior always happen when I create a new conda environment with python 2.7, this just automatically adds the .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages to PYTHONPATH.

If I create new conda environments with python3.x , this does not happen.

Does this mean that one cannot create a separate isolated conda environment for the same python version as the user-level python?

Comment: The "isolation" is mostly to prevent Conda-installed packages from leaking out.  Python always looks in `.local` for modules.  Those are user-local packages, not system-wide.  I suppose you could write a `site.py` that removes it from the path, but that seems counterproductive.

Comment: @TimRoberts but if that path were always there, we could always import modules from outside the conda environments, which is usually not the case right? I see most of my conda envs do NOT have the .local path within the environment, so this appears to be an exception

Comment: I don't know the Conda details.  `.local` was added in Python 2.6.  It's added in `site.py` and `sysconfig.py`; perhaps some Conda versions customize those.

Comment: Check if any of your activation scripts for conda manually add this path to the sys path. This is not supposed to happen by default.

Comment: @TimRoberts Conda actually removes all of the typical python search paths and creates new ones so that conda environments are not aware of any system paths.

Comment: @VikashB How can I check if my conda activation script do this? This is behavior I haven't seen in other conda environments, and for creating this one I did not do anything uncommon, I did: 'conda create -n py2 --override-channels -c conda-forge python=2.7 spyder=3.3 qtawesome=0.7', and then 'conda activate py2', nothing else. Is just removing the path from 'sys' enough or should I take more steps to make sure this does not happen?

Comment: @VikashB are you sure? I was under the impression one cannot manipulate where the `site` module searches to populate `sys.path` (other than by adding with `PYTHONPATH`). Could you link to some docs or code in the Conda codebase that supports this?

Comment: @hirschme to answer you question to Tim, Conda only finds those packages with the matching Python major.minor version. If your other Conda environments were 3.x, they would not find these 2.7 packages that are installed here at the user-level.

Comment: @merv does that mean that, if I have a user install of python 2.7, I can't have a isolated python 2.7 conda environment? It will always have access to user local python packages even not installed in the conda environment?

Comment: @merv I added an update to the question confirming the behavior you are explaining in this comment. Seems like the right track for explaining this behavior, however I am still confused as to why this is standard behavior.

Comment: Looking further into this, one can disable `site` module from adding a user-level site by launching with `-s` flag or setting the shell environment variable `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [what @VikashB mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67496860/570918), these can result from packages installed with `pip install --user`. As @TimRoberts alluded to in the comments, the `site` module, which populates the `sys.path` variable, searches paths like `~/.local/lib/python*/site-packages` by default.

### Temporary Options

One can disable the `site` module from loading such packages (see [PEP 370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)), either by launching Python with an `-s` flag (`python -s`) or by setting the environment variable PYTHONNOUSERSITE:

```
export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
python
```

### Longer-term options

#### Hiding from `site` module

If you need to keep these packages for some reason, one option is to move them to a non-default location so the `site` module doesn't find them. For example,

```bash
mkdir ~/.local/lib/py_backup
mv ~/.local/lib/python* ~/.local/lib/py_backup
```

This will effectively hide them, and they could still be used through PYTHONPATH if necessary.

#### Removal

If you don't need the packages, and only use Conda then consider just removing them

```bash
rm -r ~/.local/lib/python*
```

For reference, Conda users are discouraged from using the `--user` flag in [the Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env). Conda environments assume full isolation of environments, so leakage such as OP reports can lead to undefined behavior.

#### Experimental: envvar-pythonnousersite-true

In response to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918), I put together [a simple Conda package](https://github.com/mfansler/envvar-pythonnousersite-true) that sets the `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` variable at environment activation time. There are other ways to set environment variables, but this is a quick and minimal patch.

It can be installed with:

```bash
conda install merv::envvar-pythonnousersite-true
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible reasons why this might happen.

Check if you have any [activation scripts](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/activate-scripts.html) that manually add these paths.

Another option is to check if you have environment variables such as `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` set. If they are, then check where they are being set and remove them.

You can use `conda info -a` in an activated environment to show all the relevant variables/information.

Comment: I do not have activation scripts that manually add these paths, nor setting any enviornment variables like PYTHONPATH. I haven't customized or changed anything from the clean conda install.  Everytime I create a new conda environment with python2, it automatically gets access to my user-level python2.7 packages

Comment: You may not be setting it, but did you check if they are set/available after you activate the conda environment ? If nothing works, just remove all user level packages in that path and let conda manage all your python versions