# Conda install many packages when I install python=3.8

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda

I try to create an empty anaconda environment in order to install the `requirements.txt` file of a project.

I use the following command line :
`conda create --name lsg --no-default-packages`
`conda install python=3.8`

When I install python 3.8, conda installs many packages such as `pandas==1.2.3`, `scikit-learn==0.24.1` or `seaborn==0.11.1` and also some local packages such as`lsg==1.0`.
Which is not what I want ...

Do you know where this error can come from and how to solve it?

EDIT :
Here, you can find a sample of all the pacakges downloaded when Python 3.8 is install. It is much more than the default packages such as `pip`.

[image: packages]

It looks like conda install all packages from my base environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda environment has access to system modules, how to prevent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495221/conda-environment-has-access-to-system-modules-how-to-prevent) That is, Conda is not installing any of this, rather you have installed Python packages with `pip install —user` previously.

Comment: This can answer a part of my responce. Actually, my `.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` is full of those packages. Conda seems to install this packages when creating a new environment.
I don't know where this can be from, I never used `pip install --user`, I only use `pip3` command.

Comment: also @merv, do you know how to restore the default `site-packages` ? I suppose I shouldn't remove all of them.

Comment: To clarify, Conda is not *installing* them, rather the `site` module detects them automatically and includes them in `sys.path` (where Python searches for modules). Unless you plan on maintaining a non-Conda installation of Python you should remove them all (delete that `python3.8` folder entirely). Otherwise, you would have to move that `python3.8` folder to a different (non-default) location where the `site` module will not find them and you would use PYTHONPATH to tell the non-Conda Python installation where to find it.

Comment: thanks for your help @merv, this has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the python version for the conda environment you are creating by mentioning the version of the package.

`conda create --name lsg --no-default-packages python=3.8`

Comment: this command does not work. It also installs many packages (the same ones that were installed with my previous command lines)

Comment: Could you try using a different name for your environment perhaps, because the name `lsg` is also the name of a python package whose dependencies are being installed.

Also a few packages like `pip` will be installed by default as the bare minimum for you to use the environment in a functional way.

Comment: I tried with the env name `lsg_test` (which is not a package) and I had the same problem.

Comment: So basically Anaconda is a "data-science platform", so I'm assuming it will install the necessary packages required for an average data scientist. Try using virtualenv on python if you don't want such extra packages to be installed.
[VirtualEnv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I edit in my post, anaconda is not just install the necessary packages required for data science but all the packages from my `base` environments.

And it is not the case when I install Python=3.9 as example

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot about that, my bad.