# Pip not working in base conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

I have a conda installation which was working perfectly fine, until I created a new virtual environment using venv.Now pip wont work.

In base conda environment:

```
(base) D:\ML Projects>pip --version
Script file 'D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py' is not present.
```

In a virtual environment :

```
(base) D:\ML Projects>pytorch\Scripts\activate

(pytorch) (base) D:\ML Projects>pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from d:\ml projects\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

(pytorch) (base) D:\ML Projects>
```

These are the things that i have tried:

1. Tried reinstalling pip using conda:

```
(base) C:\Users\Me>conda install pip
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

2. upgrdaing using pip(Gives different responses):

Response1:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (21.1.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
    WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.1.1:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\scripts\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

Respnse2:

```
(base) C:\Users\Me>pip install --upgrade pip --user
Script file 'D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py' is not present.
```

Also, Have i broken my installation? If yes, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Also, when I went to the D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\ directory, I found both pip and pip3 python scripts.So I dont know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing your pip cache first might help.

In your base environment, try running:

```sh
py -m pip cache purge
py -m pip install -U pip
```

Then check the output of `pip --version`. If this still doesn't work, you may need to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks , it worked.But I have a small question. when i execute pip --version command the response is:`Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (21.1.2)` , even though my anaconda installation is on `D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`. Is this something to worry about?

Comment: @SrinjoyMukherjee yes, that usually implies you have previously installed with `pip install --user` which is not recommended for Conda users since it violates the isolation of environments. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67495221/570918

Comment: @SrinjoyMukherjee, usually you would expect this path to be `c:\users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip` for base. It might be related to which Python you have set in your PATH. Your default Python version for conda (base) is usually `c:\users\me\Anaconda3\python.exe`, so you might try adding that directory (minus the 'python.exe') to your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was caused by having a local Python 3.8 installed:

```bash
$ which -a pip
/home/<username>/.local/bin/pip
/home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/py10/bin/pip
```

See [**Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41060382/1164465)