# Conda - packages installed in other environments appear to be in base env as well

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've been using Anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04 for quite some time. I generally avoid doing anything in the base environment, using virtual environments for pretty much everything instead, so I follow the general workflow:

```
conda create --name some_env_name python=3.x
conda activate some_env_name
pip install whatever_package
```

However, I just noticed something weird.
I ran 'pip list' in the base environment, and it returned a long list of packages, most of which should be only installed in other environments.
Even weirder, some versions aren't the same, so that for example I have GluonCV  0.7.0 in the environment where I actually planned to install it, but a later version (0.8.0) in the base env.

Now, it's clearly possible that I simply got confused sometimes, and accidentally installed the packages I wanted in the base environment, before activating the environment where I actually wanted them. However, the list in the base env is pretty long, so I'd be really surprised if I were distracted so often.
Moreover, I ran:

```
​conda list -n base -r
```

and - unless I got this wrong - I was expecting to see the various moments where I accidentally installed the packages in the base env, but I got:

```
2019-07-21 19:34:56  (rev 0)
    +_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf-0.1.0
    +_libgcc_mutex-0.1
    +alabaster-0.7.12
    +anaconda-2019.07
    +anaconda-client-1.7.2
    +anaconda-navigator-1.9.7
    +anaconda-project-0.8.3
    +asn1crypto-0.24.0
    +astroid-2.2.5
    +astropy-3.2.1
    +atomicwrites-1.3.0
    +attrs-19.1.0
    +babel-2.7.0
    +backcall-0.1.0
    +backports-1.0
    +backports.functools_lru_cache-1.5
    +backports.os-0.1.1
    +backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0
    +backports.tempfile-1.0
    +backports.weakref-1.0.post1
    +beautifulsoup4-4.7.1
    +bitarray-0.9.3
    +bkcharts-0.2
    +blas-1.0
    +bleach-3.1.0
    +blosc-1.16.3
    +bokeh-1.2.0
    +boto-2.49.0
    +bottleneck-1.2.1
    +bzip2-1.0.8
    +ca-certificates-2019.5.15
    +cairo-1.14.12
    +certifi-2019.6.16
    +cffi-1.12.3
    +chardet-3.0.4
    +click-7.0
    +cloudpickle-1.2.1
    +clyent-1.2.2
    +colorama-0.4.1
    +conda-4.7.10
    +conda-build-3.18.8
    +conda-env-2.6.0
    +conda-package-handling-1.3.11
    +conda-verify-3.4.2
    +contextlib2-0.5.5
    +cryptography-2.7
    +curl-7.65.2
    +cycler-0.10.0
    +cython-0.29.12
    +cytoolz-0.10.0
    +dask-2.1.0
    +dask-core-2.1.0
    +dbus-1.13.6
    +decorator-4.4.0
    +defusedxml-0.6.0
    +distributed-2.1.0
    +docutils-0.14
    +entrypoints-0.3
    +et_xmlfile-1.0.1
    +expat-2.2.6
    +fastcache-1.1.0
    +filelock-3.0.12
    +flask-1.1.1
    +fontconfig-2.13.0
    +freetype-2.9.1
    +fribidi-1.0.5
    +future-0.17.1
    +get_terminal_size-1.0.0
    +gevent-1.4.0
    +glib-2.56.2
    +glob2-0.7
    +gmp-6.1.2
    +gmpy2-2.0.8
    +graphite2-1.3.13
    +greenlet-0.4.15
    +gst-plugins-base-1.14.0
    +gstreamer-1.14.0
    +h5py-2.9.0
    +harfbuzz-1.8.8
    +hdf5-1.10.4
    +heapdict-1.0.0
    +html5lib-1.0.1
    +icu-58.2
    +idna-2.8
    +imageio-2.5.0
    +imagesize-1.1.0
    +importlib_metadata-0.17
    +intel-openmp-2019.4
    +ipykernel-5.1.1
    +ipython-7.6.1
    +ipython_genutils-0.2.0
    +ipywidgets-7.5.0
    +isort-4.3.21
    +itsdangerous-1.1.0
    +jbig-2.1
    +jdcal-1.4.1
    +jedi-0.13.3
    +jeepney-0.4
    +jinja2-2.10.1
    +joblib-0.13.2
    +jpeg-9b
    +json5-0.8.4
    +jsonschema-3.0.1
    +jupyter-1.0.0
    +jupyter_client-5.3.1
    +jupyter_console-6.0.0
    +jupyter_core-4.5.0
    +jupyterlab-1.0.2
    +jupyterlab_server-1.0.0
    +keyring-18.0.0
    +kiwisolver-1.1.0
    +krb5-1.16.1
    +lazy-object-proxy-1.4.1
    +libarchive-3.3.3
    +libcurl-7.65.2
    +libedit-3.1.20181209
    +libffi-3.2.1
    +libgcc-ng-9.1.0
    +libgfortran-ng-7.3.0
    +liblief-0.9.0
    +libpng-1.6.37
    +libsodium-1.0.16
    +libssh2-1.8.2
    +libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0
    +libtiff-4.0.10
    +libtool-2.4.6
    +libuuid-1.0.3
    +libxcb-1.13
    +libxml2-2.9.9
    +libxslt-1.1.33
    +llvmlite-0.29.0
    +locket-0.2.0
    +lxml-4.3.4
    +lz4-c-1.8.1.2
    +lzo-2.10
    +markupsafe-1.1.1
    +matplotlib-3.1.0
    +mccabe-0.6.1
    +mistune-0.8.4
    +mkl-2019.4
    +mkl-service-2.0.2
    +mkl_fft-1.0.12
    +mkl_random-1.0.2
    +mock-3.0.5
    +more-itertools-7.0.0
    +mpc-1.1.0
    +mpfr-4.0.1
    +mpmath-1.1.0
    +msgpack-python-0.6.1
    +multipledispatch-0.6.0
    +navigator-updater-0.2.1
    +nbconvert-5.5.0
    +nbformat-4.4.0
    +ncurses-6.1
    +networkx-2.3
    +nltk-3.4.4
    +nose-1.3.7
    +notebook-6.0.0
    +numba-0.44.1
    +numexpr-2.6.9
    +numpy-1.16.4
    +numpy-base-1.16.4
    +numpydoc-0.9.1
    +olefile-0.46
    +openpyxl-2.6.2
    +openssl-1.1.1c
    +packaging-19.0
    +pandas-0.24.2
    +pandoc-2.2.3.2
    +pandocfilters-1.4.2
    +pango-1.42.4
    +parso-0.5.0
    +partd-1.0.0
    +patchelf-0.9
    +path.py-12.0.1
    +pathlib2-2.3.4
    +patsy-0.5.1
    +pcre-8.43
    +pep8-1.7.1
    +pexpect-4.7.0
    +pickleshare-0.7.5
    +pillow-6.1.0
    +pip-19.1.1
    +pixman-0.38.0
    +pkginfo-1.5.0.1
    +pluggy-0.12.0
    +ply-3.11
    +prometheus_client-0.7.1
    +prompt_toolkit-2.0.9
    +psutil-5.6.3
    +ptyprocess-0.6.0
    +py-1.8.0
    +py-lief-0.9.0
    +pycodestyle-2.5.0
    +pycosat-0.6.3
    +pycparser-2.19
    +pycrypto-2.6.1
    +pycurl-7.43.0.3
    +pyflakes-2.1.1
    +pygments-2.4.2
    +pylint-2.3.1
    +pyodbc-4.0.26
    +pyopenssl-19.0.0
    +pyparsing-2.4.0
    +pyqt-5.9.2
    +pyrsistent-0.14.11
    +pysocks-1.7.0
    +pytables-3.5.2
    +pytest-5.0.1
    +pytest-arraydiff-0.3
    +pytest-astropy-0.5.0
    +pytest-doctestplus-0.3.0
    +pytest-openfiles-0.3.2
    +pytest-remotedata-0.3.1
    +python-3.7.3
    +python-dateutil-2.8.0
    +python-libarchive-c-2.8
    +pytz-2019.1
    +pywavelets-1.0.3
    +pyyaml-5.1.1
    +pyzmq-18.0.0
    +qt-5.9.7
    +qtawesome-0.5.7
    +qtconsole-4.5.1
    +qtpy-1.8.0
    +readline-7.0
    +requests-2.22.0
    +rope-0.14.0
    +ruamel_yaml-0.15.46
    +scikit-image-0.15.0
    +scikit-learn-0.21.2
    +scipy-1.3.0
    +seaborn-0.9.0
    +secretstorage-3.1.1
    +send2trash-1.5.0
    +setuptools-41.0.1
    +simplegeneric-0.8.1
    +singledispatch-3.4.0.3
    +sip-4.19.8
    +six-1.12.0
    +snappy-1.1.7
    +snowballstemmer-1.9.0
    +sortedcollections-1.1.2
    +sortedcontainers-2.1.0
    +soupsieve-1.8
    +sphinx-2.1.2
    +sphinxcontrib-1.0
    +sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.1
    +sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.1
    +sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-1.0.2
    +sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1
    +sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.2
    +sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.3
    +sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.1.2
    +spyder-3.3.6
    +spyder-kernels-0.5.1
    +sqlalchemy-1.3.5
    +sqlite-3.29.0
    +statsmodels-0.10.0
    +sympy-1.4
    +tblib-1.4.0
    +terminado-0.8.2
    +testpath-0.4.2
    +tk-8.6.8
    +toolz-0.10.0
    +tornado-6.0.3
    +tqdm-4.32.1
    +traitlets-4.3.2
    +unicodecsv-0.14.1
    +unixodbc-2.3.7
    +urllib3-1.24.2
    +wcwidth-0.1.7
    +webencodings-0.5.1
    +werkzeug-0.15.4
    +wheel-0.33.4
    +widgetsnbextension-3.5.0
    +wrapt-1.11.2
    +wurlitzer-1.0.2
    +xlrd-1.2.0
    +xlsxwriter-1.1.8
    +xlwt-1.3.0
    +xz-5.2.4
    +yaml-0.1.7
    +zeromq-4.3.1
    +zict-1.0.0
    +zipp-0.5.1
    +zlib-1.2.11
    +zstd-1.3.7

2019-10-04 11:46:05  (rev 1)
     conda  {4.7.10 -> 4.7.12}
     conda-package-handling  {1.3.11 -> 1.6.0}

2020-05-05 10:52:25  (rev 2)
     anaconda-navigator  {1.9.7 -> 1.9.12}
     conda  {4.7.12 -> 4.8.3}
    +tbb-2020.0
    +xmltodict-0.12.0

2021-06-14 16:41:36  (rev 3)
     _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf  {0.1.0 -> 0.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     _libgcc_mutex  {0.1 -> 0.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     alabaster  {0.7.12 -> 0.7.12 (defaults/linux-64)}
     anaconda  {2019.07 -> 2019.07 (defaults/linux-64)}
     anaconda-client  {1.7.2 -> 1.7.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     anaconda-navigator  {1.9.12 -> 2.0.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     anaconda-project  {0.8.3 -> 0.8.3 (defaults/noarch)}
     asn1crypto  {0.24.0 -> 0.24.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     astroid  {2.2.5 -> 2.2.5 (defaults/linux-64)}
     astropy  {3.2.1 -> 3.2.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     atomicwrites  {1.3.0 -> 1.3.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     attrs  {19.1.0 -> 19.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     babel  {2.7.0 -> 2.7.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     backcall  {0.1.0 -> 0.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     backports  {1.0 -> 1.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     backports.functools_lru_cache  {1.5 -> 1.6.4 (defaults/noarch)}
     backports.os  {0.1.1 -> 0.1.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     backports.shutil_get_terminal_size  {1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     backports.tempfile  {1.0 -> 1.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     backports.weakref  {1.0.post1 -> 1.0.post1 (defaults/noarch)}
     beautifulsoup4  {4.7.1 -> 4.7.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     bitarray  {0.9.3 -> 0.9.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     bkcharts  {0.2 -> 0.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     blas  {1.0 -> 1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     bleach  {3.1.0 -> 3.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     blosc  {1.16.3 -> 1.16.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     bokeh  {1.2.0 -> 1.2.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     boto  {2.49.0 -> 2.49.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     bottleneck  {1.2.1 -> 1.2.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     bzip2  {1.0.8 -> 1.0.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     ca-certificates  {2019.5.15 -> 2019.5.15 (defaults/linux-64)}
     cairo  {1.14.12 -> 1.14.12 (defaults/linux-64)}
     certifi  {2019.6.16 -> 2019.6.16 (defaults/linux-64)}
     cffi  {1.12.3 -> 1.12.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     chardet  {3.0.4 -> 3.0.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     click  {7.0 -> 7.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     cloudpickle  {1.2.1 -> 1.2.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     clyent  {1.2.2 -> 1.2.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     colorama  {0.4.1 -> 0.4.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     conda  {4.8.3 -> 4.10.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     conda-build  {3.18.8 -> 3.18.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     conda-env  {2.6.0 -> 2.6.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     conda-package-handling  {1.6.0 -> 1.7.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     conda-verify  {3.4.2 -> 3.4.2 (defaults/noarch)}
     contextlib2  {0.5.5 -> 0.5.5 (defaults/linux-64)}
     cryptography  {2.7 -> 2.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
     curl  {7.65.2 -> 7.65.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     cycler  {0.10.0 -> 0.10.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     cython  {0.29.12 -> 0.29.12 (defaults/linux-64)}
     cytoolz  {0.10.0 -> 0.10.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     dask  {2.1.0 -> 2.1.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     dask-core  {2.1.0 -> 2.1.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     dbus  {1.13.6 -> 1.13.6 (defaults/linux-64)}
     decorator  {4.4.0 -> 4.4.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     defusedxml  {0.6.0 -> 0.6.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     distributed  {2.1.0 -> 2.1.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     docutils  {0.14 -> 0.14 (defaults/linux-64)}
     entrypoints  {0.3 -> 0.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     et_xmlfile  {1.0.1 -> 1.0.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     expat  {2.2.6 -> 2.2.6 (defaults/linux-64)}
     fastcache  {1.1.0 -> 1.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     filelock  {3.0.12 -> 3.0.12 (defaults/noarch)}
     flask  {1.1.1 -> 1.1.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     fontconfig  {2.13.0 -> 2.13.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     freetype  {2.9.1 -> 2.9.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     fribidi  {1.0.5 -> 1.0.5 (defaults/linux-64)}
     future  {0.17.1 -> 0.18.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     get_terminal_size  {1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     gevent  {1.4.0 -> 1.4.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     glib  {2.56.2 -> 2.56.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     glob2  {0.7 -> 0.7 (defaults/noarch)}
     gmp  {6.1.2 -> 6.1.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     gmpy2  {2.0.8 -> 2.0.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     graphite2  {1.3.13 -> 1.3.13 (defaults/linux-64)}
     greenlet  {0.4.15 -> 0.4.15 (defaults/linux-64)}
     gst-plugins-base  {1.14.0 -> 1.14.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     gstreamer  {1.14.0 -> 1.14.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     h5py  {2.9.0 -> 2.9.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     harfbuzz  {1.8.8 -> 1.8.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     hdf5  {1.10.4 -> 1.10.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     heapdict  {1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     html5lib  {1.0.1 -> 1.0.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     icu  {58.2 -> 58.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     idna  {2.8 -> 2.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     imageio  {2.5.0 -> 2.5.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     imagesize  {1.1.0 -> 1.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     importlib_metadata  {0.17 -> 0.17 (defaults/linux-64)}
     intel-openmp  {2019.4 -> 2019.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     ipykernel  {5.1.1 -> 5.1.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     ipython  {7.6.1 -> 7.6.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     ipython_genutils  {0.2.0 -> 0.2.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     ipywidgets  {7.5.0 -> 7.5.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     isort  {4.3.21 -> 4.3.21 (defaults/linux-64)}
     itsdangerous  {1.1.0 -> 1.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jbig  {2.1 -> 2.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jdcal  {1.4.1 -> 1.4.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     jedi  {0.13.3 -> 0.13.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jeepney  {0.4 -> 0.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jinja2  {2.10.1 -> 2.10.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     joblib  {0.13.2 -> 0.13.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jpeg  {9b -> 9b (defaults/linux-64)}
     json5  {0.8.4 -> 0.8.4 (defaults/noarch)}
     jsonschema  {3.0.1 -> 3.0.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jupyter  {1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jupyter_client  {5.3.1 -> 5.3.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     jupyter_console  {6.0.0 -> 6.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jupyter_core  {4.5.0 -> 4.5.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     jupyterlab  {1.0.2 -> 1.0.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jupyterlab_server  {1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     keyring  {18.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     kiwisolver  {1.1.0 -> 1.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     krb5  {1.16.1 -> 1.16.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     lazy-object-proxy  {1.4.1 -> 1.4.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libarchive  {3.3.3 -> 3.3.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libcurl  {7.65.2 -> 7.65.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libedit  {3.1.20181209 -> 3.1.20181209 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libffi  {3.2.1 -> 3.2.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libgcc-ng  {9.1.0 -> 9.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libgfortran-ng  {7.3.0 -> 7.3.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     liblief  {0.9.0 -> 0.9.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libpng  {1.6.37 -> 1.6.37 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libsodium  {1.0.16 -> 1.0.16 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libssh2  {1.8.2 -> 1.8.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libstdcxx-ng  {9.1.0 -> 9.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libtiff  {4.0.10 -> 4.0.10 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libtool  {2.4.6 -> 2.4.6 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libuuid  {1.0.3 -> 1.0.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libxcb  {1.13 -> 1.13 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libxml2  {2.9.9 -> 2.9.9 (defaults/linux-64)}
     libxslt  {1.1.33 -> 1.1.33 (defaults/linux-64)}
     llvmlite  {0.29.0 -> 0.29.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     locket  {0.2.0 -> 0.2.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     lxml  {4.3.4 -> 4.3.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     lz4-c  {1.8.1.2 -> 1.8.1.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     lzo  {2.10 -> 2.10 (defaults/linux-64)}
     markupsafe  {1.1.1 -> 1.1.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     matplotlib  {3.1.0 -> 3.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mccabe  {0.6.1 -> 0.6.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mistune  {0.8.4 -> 0.8.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mkl  {2019.4 -> 2019.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mkl-service  {2.0.2 -> 2.0.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mkl_fft  {1.0.12 -> 1.0.12 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mkl_random  {1.0.2 -> 1.0.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mock  {3.0.5 -> 3.0.5 (defaults/linux-64)}
     more-itertools  {7.0.0 -> 7.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mpc  {1.1.0 -> 1.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mpfr  {4.0.1 -> 4.0.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     mpmath  {1.1.0 -> 1.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     msgpack-python  {0.6.1 -> 0.6.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     multipledispatch  {0.6.0 -> 0.6.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     navigator-updater  {0.2.1 -> 0.2.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     nbconvert  {5.5.0 -> 5.5.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     nbformat  {4.4.0 -> 4.4.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     ncurses  {6.1 -> 6.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     networkx  {2.3 -> 2.3 (defaults/noarch)}
     nltk  {3.4.4 -> 3.4.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     nose  {1.3.7 -> 1.3.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
     notebook  {6.0.0 -> 6.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     numba  {0.44.1 -> 0.44.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     numexpr  {2.6.9 -> 2.6.9 (defaults/linux-64)}
     numpy  {1.16.4 -> 1.16.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     numpy-base  {1.16.4 -> 1.16.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     numpydoc  {0.9.1 -> 0.9.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     olefile  {0.46 -> 0.46 (defaults/linux-64)}
     openpyxl  {2.6.2 -> 2.6.2 (defaults/noarch)}
     openssl  {1.1.1c -> 1.1.1c (defaults/linux-64)}
     packaging  {19.0 -> 19.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pandas  {0.24.2 -> 0.24.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pandoc  {2.2.3.2 -> 2.2.3.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pandocfilters  {1.4.2 -> 1.4.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pango  {1.42.4 -> 1.42.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     parso  {0.5.0 -> 0.5.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     partd  {1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     patchelf  {0.9 -> 0.9 (defaults/linux-64)}
     path.py  {12.0.1 -> 12.0.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     pathlib2  {2.3.4 -> 2.3.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     patsy  {0.5.1 -> 0.5.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pcre  {8.43 -> 8.43 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pep8  {1.7.1 -> 1.7.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pexpect  {4.7.0 -> 4.7.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pickleshare  {0.7.5 -> 0.7.5 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pillow  {6.1.0 -> 6.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pip  {19.1.1 -> 19.1.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pixman  {0.38.0 -> 0.38.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pkginfo  {1.5.0.1 -> 1.5.0.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pluggy  {0.12.0 -> 0.12.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     ply  {3.11 -> 3.11 (defaults/linux-64)}
     prometheus_client  {0.7.1 -> 0.7.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     prompt_toolkit  {2.0.9 -> 2.0.9 (defaults/linux-64)}
     psutil  {5.6.3 -> 5.6.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     ptyprocess  {0.6.0 -> 0.6.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     py  {1.8.0 -> 1.8.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     py-lief  {0.9.0 -> 0.9.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pycodestyle  {2.5.0 -> 2.5.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pycosat  {0.6.3 -> 0.6.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pycparser  {2.19 -> 2.19 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pycrypto  {2.6.1 -> 2.6.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pycurl  {7.43.0.3 -> 7.43.0.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pyflakes  {2.1.1 -> 2.1.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pygments  {2.4.2 -> 2.4.2 (defaults/noarch)}
     pylint  {2.3.1 -> 2.3.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pyodbc  {4.0.26 -> 4.0.26 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pyopenssl  {19.0.0 -> 19.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pyparsing  {2.4.0 -> 2.4.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     pyqt  {5.9.2 -> 5.9.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pyrsistent  {0.14.11 -> 0.14.11 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pysocks  {1.7.0 -> 1.7.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pytables  {3.5.2 -> 3.5.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pytest  {5.0.1 -> 5.0.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pytest-arraydiff  {0.3 -> 0.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pytest-astropy  {0.5.0 -> 0.5.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pytest-doctestplus  {0.3.0 -> 0.3.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pytest-openfiles  {0.3.2 -> 0.3.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pytest-remotedata  {0.3.1 -> 0.3.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     python  {3.7.3 -> 3.7.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     python-dateutil  {2.8.0 -> 2.8.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     python-libarchive-c  {2.8 -> 2.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pytz  {2019.1 -> 2019.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     pywavelets  {1.0.3 -> 1.0.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pyyaml  {5.1.1 -> 5.1.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     pyzmq  {18.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     qt  {5.9.7 -> 5.9.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
     qtawesome  {0.5.7 -> 0.5.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
     qtconsole  {4.5.1 -> 4.5.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     qtpy  {1.8.0 -> 1.8.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     readline  {7.0 -> 7.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     requests  {2.22.0 -> 2.22.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     rope  {0.14.0 -> 0.14.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     ruamel_yaml  {0.15.46 -> 0.15.46 (defaults/linux-64)}
     scikit-image  {0.15.0 -> 0.15.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     scikit-learn  {0.21.2 -> 0.21.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     scipy  {1.3.0 -> 1.3.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     seaborn  {0.9.0 -> 0.9.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     secretstorage  {3.1.1 -> 3.1.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     send2trash  {1.5.0 -> 1.5.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     setuptools  {41.0.1 -> 41.0.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     simplegeneric  {0.8.1 -> 0.8.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     singledispatch  {3.4.0.3 -> 3.4.0.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     sip  {4.19.8 -> 4.19.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     six  {1.12.0 -> 1.12.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     snappy  {1.1.7 -> 1.1.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
     snowballstemmer  {1.9.0 -> 1.9.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     sortedcollections  {1.1.2 -> 1.1.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     sortedcontainers  {2.1.0 -> 2.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     soupsieve  {1.8 -> 1.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     sphinx  {2.1.2 -> 2.1.2 (defaults/noarch)}
     sphinxcontrib  {1.0 -> 1.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     sphinxcontrib-applehelp  {1.0.1 -> 1.0.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     sphinxcontrib-devhelp  {1.0.1 -> 1.0.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp  {1.0.2 -> 1.0.2 (defaults/noarch)}
     sphinxcontrib-jsmath  {1.0.1 -> 1.0.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     sphinxcontrib-qthelp  {1.0.2 -> 1.0.2 (defaults/noarch)}
     sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml  {1.1.3 -> 1.1.3 (defaults/noarch)}
     sphinxcontrib-websupport  {1.1.2 -> 1.1.2 (defaults/noarch)}
     spyder  {3.3.6 -> 3.3.6 (defaults/linux-64)}
     spyder-kernels  {0.5.1 -> 0.5.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     sqlalchemy  {1.3.5 -> 1.3.5 (defaults/linux-64)}
     sqlite  {3.29.0 -> 3.29.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     statsmodels  {0.10.0 -> 0.10.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     sympy  {1.4 -> 1.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     tbb  {2020.0 -> 2021.2.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     tblib  {1.4.0 -> 1.4.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     terminado  {0.8.2 -> 0.8.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     testpath  {0.4.2 -> 0.4.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     tk  {8.6.8 -> 8.6.8 (defaults/linux-64)}
     toolz  {0.10.0 -> 0.10.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     tornado  {6.0.3 -> 6.0.3 (defaults/linux-64)}
     tqdm  {4.32.1 -> 4.32.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     traitlets  {4.3.2 -> 4.3.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     unicodecsv  {0.14.1 -> 0.14.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     unixodbc  {2.3.7 -> 2.3.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
     urllib3  {1.24.2 -> 1.24.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     wcwidth  {0.1.7 -> 0.1.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
     webencodings  {0.5.1 -> 0.5.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     werkzeug  {0.15.4 -> 0.15.4 (defaults/noarch)}
     wheel  {0.33.4 -> 0.33.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     widgetsnbextension  {3.5.0 -> 3.5.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     wrapt  {1.11.2 -> 1.11.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     wurlitzer  {1.0.2 -> 1.0.2 (defaults/linux-64)}
     xlrd  {1.2.0 -> 1.2.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     xlsxwriter  {1.1.8 -> 1.1.8 (defaults/noarch)}
     xlwt  {1.3.0 -> 1.3.0 (defaults/linux-64)}
     xmltodict  {0.12.0 -> 0.12.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     xz  {5.2.4 -> 5.2.4 (defaults/linux-64)}
     yaml  {0.1.7 -> 0.1.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
     zeromq  {4.3.1 -> 4.3.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     zict  {1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     zipp  {0.5.1 -> 0.5.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     zlib  {1.2.11 -> 1.2.11 (defaults/linux-64)}
     zstd  {1.3.7 -> 1.3.7 (defaults/linux-64)}
    +conda-content-trust-0.1.1 (defaults/noarch)
    +conda-repo-cli-1.0.4 (defaults/noarch)
    +conda-token-0.3.0 (defaults/noarch)
```

And I see no reference here of the packages that are in base, but shouldn't (mxnet, gluoncv, tensorflow).
So, am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: I have faced almost the same problem, I found link: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429 you can use it to solve this problem like this: ```conda create -n env pip``` I just installed pip

Answer (score 1):

First, Conda's revision list does not track `pip`-installed packages, whereas `conda list` and `conda env export` will detect them. So, even if you did mistakenly install in **base** using `pip`, you can't get a history through Conda.

Second, another possibility is environment leakage. This usually arises from user- or system-level installs (e.g., `pip install --user`). [Other questions address this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495221/conda-environment-has-access-to-system-modules-how-to-prevent) Running the `pip` module from an isolated Python instance should exclude these, e.g.,

```bash
python -I -m pip list
```

or compare the two with

```bash
diff <(pip list) <(python -I -m pip list)
```

Otherwise, manually looking through the `anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` directory will show exactly what Python packages are installed in **base**.

Comment: I tried running diff <(pip list) <(python -I -m pip list), and it didn't return anything. So, this means that the packages in base do not depend on user installations or environment leakage, but that I actually accidentally installed them with pip in the base env?

Comment: To be sure, check the `site-packages` directory manually for some of the packages you have questions about. Also, do you have `PYTHONPATH` set (check `echo $PYTHONPATH`)? It should be empty.

Comment: PYTHONPATH is empty and yes, all the package folders are in site-packages