# New anaconda environment starts with packages I didn't install

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, conda

I've been trying to resolve broken pytorch installations, and have made several fresh starts by deleting an environment with `conda remove -n <env> --all` and re-creating it. At some point I noticed that the freshly created environment is not "fresh" at all: when launching python from that environment, I was still able to `import` the packages from the removed environment of the same name, namely `pytorch`, which was not installed in the `base` environment (`activate base` followed by trying to import `pytorch` does not work, as expected). I have tried

```
conda create -n <random name>
```

and even the randomly named, empty environment has `pytorch` inexplicably installed. Running `conda clean --all` before creating the environment does not prevent this from happening.

What is causing this, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda environment has access to system modules, how to prevent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495221/conda-environment-has-access-to-system-modules-how-to-prevent)

Comment: Also, what you show is empty environment creation, which is a separate issue. Namely, new environments *do not include anything* - including `python` - and therefore `which python` likely points to a different Python environment on your PATH.